# Angular 5 layout template

Tags: html, angular

I am looking for best practise how to define customisable global application layout in Angular. In .NET this has been achieved by using Master Pages. Basically, I want to define global layout (menu, header, content, footer placement) in one location and then re-use it in all pages that inherit from this layout; **including** posibility to modify layout from child to parent (ie: some page has modified menu, footer or needs to inject some extra buttons to header)

Is there any recommended best practise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to have reusable css, u can write it in `style.css` and then you can use those classes in every component of your application you want.
But if you want import things such as menu, header, footer I suggest you to create the single components for these sections and then use a component to contain the skeleton of your application:

```
//skeleton.component.html
<div>
  <app-header></app-header>
  <app-menu></app-menu>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

Then every component has is own css and you don't need to import it in the several contents. The directive `router-outlet` leads you towards the components choosen in `router.module.ts`

**EDIT 1:**

In your page.component.html you should do something like this:

```
@Output() content-for-header;
```

In your skeleton.html:

```
<app-header [content-from-page]="content-for-header"></app-header>
```

In your header.html:

```
@Input() content-from-page;
```

Comment: This looks like some vague comment to me, not like a decent answer.

Comment: I've updated for a better understanding

Comment: This is pretty obvious, I do use that model now. But. How do I modify content of <app-header> from page.component.html or in other words how do I add extra button to some context menu in <app-menu> ?

Comment: I've updated the answer. If it helps you, can you accept this answer by clicking on the V. It may help other people.

Comment: @Luke1988 You can pass the menu items as an object to the child using `@Input()` if the menu items are very different usually. If menu Items are all same except you want to add some, you can use a templateRef along with a templateOutlet to inject the extra items.

Comment: Thank you veru much, also for editing the other question of mine. That is exactly what I was asking for. I will google for more info